# How to detect double press for keys in onKeyEvent in accessibility service?

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility

this is my first question.

I have a problem trying to detect double pressing of hardware keys in accessibility service. I want to open another app pressing twice or thrice the VOLUME UP button in one second, if the second ends before the button is pressed for second or third time, just up the volume normally.

This is how i'm trying to do override onKeyEvent:

```
override fun onKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        when (event?.keyCode) {
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP -> {
                if (pressed twice in one second) {
                    Open another app
                  }
                  return super.onKeyEvent(event)

            }

        }
        return super.onKeyEvent(event)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)){
        //Do something
    }
    return true;
}
```

you can use this function to detect clicks. Then try to use handler to detect second click within several seconds.

Comment: There is no such function